# Diazed fuse heat dissipation

Tags: heat, fuses

To be more precise, I'm interested in the amount of "created" heat during normal operation from a diazed 16 ampere fuse.

How hot will the fuse be after delivered 16A in seven hours with the voltage of 230VAC, in a nominal environment of 30C.

Comment: Depends on how good you cool it and what its resistance is.

Comment: Normal working conditions and 25C ambient temperature.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To solve that you need to calculate the power dissipated in the fuse (P = IR) and then the total thermal resistance between the fuse and the ambient. This would be then similar to a heatsink calculation and there are many examples of this on the web.

You are unlikely to find thermal resistance of a fuseholder published so your best bet would be to form an experiment:

- Set up a fusebox and place the fuse in question into the holder.
- Run an appropriate current through the fuse into a test load. This can be a low voltage setup such as car battery and lamps. Using low voltage would allow you to install a temperature sensor beside the fuse.
- Run the test until the temperature stabilises.
- Calculate the thermal resistance using formula:

  $$ R_{Th} = \frac {\Delta T}{P} $$

where \$R_{Th}\$ is the thermal resistance of your fuse and holder, \$ \Delta T \$ is the difference in temperature between your fuse and ambient and P is the power dissipated in the fuse. The result will be in K/W (kelvin per watt).

You can then use this figure to predict temperature rise for any other current through *that* fuse.

Answer (score 1):

The circuit voltage is irrelevant, only the 15A current matters. Why?

After 7 hours, it will have reached steady state. The thermal conductivity from the fuse to ambient will be all-important, and it's not only not well controlled, it's usually unspecified anywhere. It's easier to measure the fuse temperature, than it is to try to work it out.

Comment: I can see in standards, that fuse carrier have a 4W (DII) power loss and shall be able withstand 185C in x days. Just want to know the nominal working heat temperature actually at max rated power at x ambient. 15A was just an example. This to get a sens of how hot the environment can be.

Comment: The fuse carrier and fuse box will have a maximum environmental temperature specification. The temperature of the fuse is irrelevant to you, the user, if you are using it in a correctly mounted fuse holder in a fuse box.

Comment: Neil, I'm asking cause it matter to me, what the heat could be. I'm not asking this question out of an user perspective :)